# Pandas Data frame from complex data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe which has data as below

```
                cert                              meta
      {"alternate_names": [                  {"asset_name": "",
                                      "audience": "External",
        "asset_name": "",              "automation_utility": "",
        "audience": "External",             "delegate_owner": "",
        "automation_utility": "",               "environment": dev
        "delegate_owner": "",               "l2_group_email": null,
        "environment": dev              "l3_group_email": null,
        "l2_group_email": null,             "requestor_email": "",
        "l3_group_email": null,             "support_email": "",
        "requestor_email": "",              "tech_delegate_email": null,
        "support_email": "",                "tech_owner_email": null
        "tech_delegate_email": null,            }
        "tech_owner_email": null    
    }   
       cert does not exists                 cert does not exists
       cert does not exists                 cert does not exists
```

I checked the datatype of the column and it shows object .I need to create a Dataframe out of status,support_email but not all rows have similar values.

In case the status does not exists need to show null.

Things I tried -:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["cert"] = df["cert"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)) )
df2 = df["cert"].apply(pd.Series )
print(df)
```

Can someone please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have (mangled?) JSON content in your dataframe.
You might be able to parse this with the Python JSON library and make it
into a dictionary. Then, you could use each dictionary to load the status
and support_email into a dataframe.

Please see example below, where I have taken one cell of the meta column of your
example dataframe, corrected for JSON errors, then ran it through the JSON
loader.

```
import json

s = '''
{"asset_name": "",
"audience": "External",
"automation_utility": "",
"delegate_owner": "",
"environment": "dev",
"l2_group_email": null,
"l3_group_email": null,
"requestor_email": "",
"support_email": "",
"tech_delegate_email": null,
"tech_owner_email": null,
"tech_delegate_email": null
}
'''

d1 = json.loads(s)
print(d1['environment'])
# dev
```